# ValueError: images do not match when blending pictures in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been messing around in python to see if I could "mix" two pictures together. What I mean by that is so that the image is transparent and you can see two pictures together. If that still does not make sense check out this link: (only I would mix a picture and a picture not a gif)

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/652564556211683363/662770085844221963/communism.gif

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open('oip.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('star.jpg')

bg = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0)
bg.save('star_oip_paste.jpg', quality=95)
```

and I get the error:

```
line 6, in <module> bg = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0) ValueError: images do not match
```

I'm not even sure if I'm using the right function for "mixing" two images together — so if I'm not, let me know.

Comment: You probably just need to ensure the images are the same width and height.  See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.blend

Comment: After opening both the images, you can resize one of them to match the other by using the [`Image.resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) function before blending them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things going on here:

- Your input images are both JPEG which doesn't support transparency, so you can only get a fixed blending throughout your image. I mean you can't see one image at one point and the other image at another. You will only see the same proportion of each image at each point. Is that what you want?

For example, if I take Paddington and Buckingham Palace and take 50% of each:

[image]

[image]

I get this:

[image]

If that's what you want, you need to resize the images to a common size and change this line:

```
bg = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0)
```

to

```
bg = Image.blend(im1, im2, 0.5)          # blend half and half
```

- If you want to paste something with transparency, so it only shows up in certain places, you need to load the overlay from a GIF or PNG with transparency and use:

  background.paste(overlay, box=None, mask=overlay)

Then you can do this - note you can see different amounts of the two images at each point:

[image]

So, as a concrete example of overlaying a transparent image onto an opaque background, and starting with Paddington (400x400) and this star (500x500):

[image]

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open background and foreground and ensure they are RGB (not palette)
bg = Image.open('paddington.png').convert('RGB')
fg = Image.open('star.png').convert('RGBA')

# Resize foreground down from 500x500 to 100x100
fg_resized = fg.resize((100,100))

# Overlay foreground onto background at top right corner, using transparency of foreground as mask
bg.paste(fg_resized,box=(300,0),mask=fg_resized)

# Save result
bg.save('result.png')
```

[image]

If you want to grab an image from a website, use this:

```
from PIL import Image 
import requests 
from io import BytesIO                                                                      

# Grab the star image from this answer
response = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKQCT.png')                              

# Make it into a PIL image
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

Comment: Yes I would like the images to be transparent so thank you. One last question though. I literally just saw PIL because I wanted to do this, so I don’t know how to resize pictures. Would you be gracious enough to explain that to me? Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer for you with concrete example of resizing and overlaying.

Comment: Last question. Is there a way to download a file from a link using PIL? or maybe a way to mix a picture from a link and a jpg picture?

Comment: I have added an example at the end, using `requests` module.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could try with OpenCV (depending on your desired output)

[image: this is the result of the code]

```
    import cv2
 
# Read the images
     foreground = cv2.imread("puppets.png")
     background = cv2.imread("ocean.png")
     alpha = cv2.imread("puppets_alpha.png")
 
# Convert uint8 to float
     foreground = foreground.astype(float)
     background = background.astype(float)
 
# Normalize the alpha mask to keep intensity between 0 and 1
     alpha = alpha.astype(float)/255
 
# Multiply the foreground with the alpha matte
     foreground = cv2.multiply(alpha, foreground)
 
# Multiply the background with ( 1 - alpha )
     background = cv2.multiply(1.0 - alpha, background)
 
# Add the masked foreground and background.
     outImage = cv2.add(foreground, background)
 
# Display image
     cv2.imshow("outImg", outImage/255)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```