# Figure out the size of image which downloaded from an url in Python

Tags: python, image, python-requests, dimensions

Program to download an image from a given *URL*

```
import requests

url = f"https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/296/372/981/wall-e-pixar-disney-movies-wallpaper-preview.jpg"

response : requests.Response = requests.get(url)
print(response.headers)
```

I want to understand how to find out the `dimensions(width x height)` of image.

`Content-Length` which is in `headers` of the `response` gives how many `bytes`(including red, green & blue channel) that image contains but not the **dimensions**.

`response.content` gives the content of image which are bytes but how to find the dimension of  the image?

Using `PIL.Image.size` we can also get the size of image but I want to understand how to get that from `response` which we get.

I have refferred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460218/get-image-size-without-downloading-it-in-python) of StackOverflow but the answer by [ElJeffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666774/eljeffe) I cannot understand.

Comment: You could parse the JPEG yourself. Why you would want to do this when you could use PIL is beyond me.

Comment: If response.content contains the image data you will need to determine the image file format (e.g. png, jpg, gif,...), then extract the bytes that determine image dimensions for that particular format (different for every format, and possibly quite complicated).  The other answer you refer to downloads just a little bit of the file image file -- the bit that is likely to contain image dimensions -- and feeds it to PIL to decode.

Comment: See last part of this answer to get a PIL Image from a requests response https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586273/2836621